# throw Exception in Record's compact constructor

Tags: java

I have a record class with compact constructor.

```
public record myRecord(int i) {
    public myRecord {
        throw new RuntimeException();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        var v = new myRecord(1);
    }
}
```

My understand is that it is same as below class. I only need to add logic to compact constructor. Compiler will add in assignment.

```
class testClass{
    int i;

    public testClass(int i) {
        throw new RuntimeException();
        this.i = i;
    }
}
```

testClass will get warning about **Unreachable statement** for this.i = i; But there is no warning on myRecord. How to explain this?

Comment: what statement do you expect to be unreachable in myRecord?

Comment: @f1sh Likely the implicit `this.i = i` that's assumed to be there.

Answer (score 3):

Because the two are not the same. If we have:

```java
public record Foo(int i) {}
```

Then the following byte-code is generated for the constructor (using Java 21 to compile):

```
public Foo(int);
  Code:
      0: aload_0
      1: invokespecial #1                  // Method java/lang/Record."<init>":()V
      4: aload_0
      5: iload_1
      6: putfield      #7                  // Field i:I
      9: return
```

As you can see, there's an assignment to the field `i`. But if we change `Foo` to:

```java
public record Foo(int i) {

    public Foo {
        throw new RuntimeException();
    }
}
```

Then the constructor's byte-code becomes:

```
public Foo(int);
  Code:
      0: aload_0
      1: invokespecial #1                  // Method java/lang/Record."<init>":()V
      4: new           #7                  // class java/lang/RuntimeException
      7: dup
      8: invokespecial #9                  // Method java/lang/RuntimeException."<init>":()V
    11: athrow
```

No attempt is made to assign `i`. It simply throws the exception. So, as a normal class, it would be as if you wrote the following (completely legal) code:

```java
public final class Foo {

    private final int i;

    public Foo(int i) {
        throw new RuntimeException();
    }

    // ... hashCode, equals, toString, and getter omitted for brevity ...
}
```

Where there's no `this.i = i` in the constructor, neither before nor after the `throw` statement.

Answer (score 0):

You are right. The object is not yet initialized when you throw your exception.
There is no warning with the compact constructor throwing values explicitly.

In any case, it's not really visible outside the object as a reference does not yet exist.